# ModelBuilder: How to extract data by date, export to separate tables and interpolate tables to rasters

Tags: python, raster, arcpy, modelbuilder, interpolation

I've been using ArcGIS for a couple years, but when it comes to model builder I've only worked with very simple models.  I'm hoping someone that is much smarter than myself can help me in building a complicated model.

I've got a very large table of data (about 300k rows) that contains points with lat/lon data, wind speed and date/time.  There are about 60 different points with wind values that have been recorded for each hour during 2012.  What I'd like to do is build a model that will:

1. Iterate through each row and select/export the data associated with first hour (00Z) Jan 1st 2012 (about 60 rows) to a separate table, then the 2nd hour (01Z) of Jan 1st 2012 to its own separate table and so on through all of 2012.
2. Perform Inverse Distance Weighting on all of the hourly tables with lat/lon and wind values that were created from step 1 above
3. Reclassify the rasters so that points in the raster that have wind values of 5 or greater are reclassified to "1" and all other cell's wind values are reclassified to "0"
4. Then iterate through the rasters created in step 3 and use something like "Collect Values" & "Cell Statistics" to sum up all of the rasters into a final summed raster for all hours in 2012.

Was going to include screenshot of my data, but I guess since this is my first post I'm not trusted yet.  I've broken the date down several different ways (just date, just time, date-time, and date-time in text format) because I've had issues trying to iterate through and select the data in my original, very large table only by date.

Hopefully I provided enough information, but if not I will try to go into more detail.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: To be honest, you may want to consider a Python script that will loop through everything. Model builder will be cumbersome with nearly 52 iterations. It's possible, but there would be a LOT of copy/pasting and setting up each and every tool. How familiar are you with Python?

It's also not very clear what you need on step 4. Are you wanting nearly 52 raster summaries to be produced in the end? Or a TOTAL of ALL rasters in ONE raster?

Comment: @angelspatial By what process do you arrive at 52 rasters? 2011 had 8,760 hours in it.

Comment: @whuber wow, you're right. For some reason I counted it as weeks, not hours. Yeah, don't use model builder for this - ever.

Comment: Right, there would be many, many rasters by the end of step 3...roughly 8,760.  I opted for model builder because I'm even less familiar with writing in python.  I'd be willing to try, but would probably need a lot of assistance.

Comment: How large do you need your output raster to be, Daniel?  (How many rows and columns?)  Also, do you have complete data for all 60 locations or are the data occasionally missing at some of them? Incidentally, you don't need to have 8760 rasters at the end: you will have the last raster you computed (which you can delete) together with the *cumulative* values from all 8760 of them: just two rasters all told.

Comment: Thanks, whuber.  I tested out manually creating a few rasters and the output raster should be about 620 columns and 250 rows. And you're right, completely forgot that the end result would be just the one final raster.  Oh, and yes, there are several hours in which there is missing data for some points.

Comment: One of us could probably help you get started on a Python script. Are you familiar enough to at least know how to troubleshoot or edit values to fit your needs? We couldn't write it perfectly for you, but we could help you get the gist of going forward. Now's a good time to familiarize yourself with arcpy if you haven't already. Do you know how to run a script?

Comment: Thank you, angelspatial.  I've written some basic shell scripts...haven't written much of anything with Python, but I'll certainly try and familiarize myself with arcpy tonight and tomorrow.  As far as running scripts, I've run plenty of shell scripts, but again not so much with Python. I'm assuming it'd be pretty similar?  I think I know enough that I could tweak and troubleshoot as necessary.  I greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5):

**Using Spatial Analyst,** we can expect each iteration of IDW, thresholding, and accumulation of results to take from a fraction of a second to a few seconds.  Multiplying by 24 * 365 = 8760 hours in a year suggests **this calculation will take hours at the least.**

It can be much faster.  Faster is not always better, but here--because there are significant issues concerning the interpolation method, since IDW is unlikely to be accurate for such data--it will be real advantage to be able to carry out the calculations quickly on a realistic scale in order to see the results and experiment with other options.

To illustrate this and to estimate how quickly it can really be done, I implemented the full-scale calculation in `R` using simulated data.  (It is a simple matter to read your data into `R` and export the resulting grid in ESRI format using, say, the `Raster` package.)  After the usual preliminaries of getting the data into the right format (values are stored in a 60 by 8760 array and point locations in a 60 by 2 array of (x,y) coordinates), handling missing values, and so on, the entire computation comes down to two lines of code:

```
thresh <- threshold * xy %*% one  # Compute the denominators
a <- matrix(rowMeans(xy %*% z >= thresh), n.x, n.y)
```

`xy` has precomputed the IDW weights (unnormalized).  `one` indicates where data are not missing and `z` is the matrix of all the data.  The two matrix multiplications `xy %*% one` and `xy %*% z` compute the denominators and numerators of all the 8760 IDW calculations at once.  The comparison in the second line creates the 8760 grids of ones and zeros and `rowMeans` averages them for the entire year.  The result, `a`, is a single grid of dimensions `n.x` and `n.y`.

By reducing this large number of linear interpolations to a few matrix operations, the fastest possible speed and efficiency can be attained.  Moreover, this approach is general: literally *any* linear interpolation method (such as Kriging) can be implemented in this fashion.

On my workstation (running this on a single core even though massive parallelization is possible) it takes just under 60 seconds to process one-quarter of the grid.  By reducing the grid resolution little detail is lost and **the entire year's data can be processed in seconds.**

**To illustrate,** here are the results for 60 points and 8760 hours on a 125 by 310 grid (half resolution; 58 seconds total time).  For simplicity it uses all available data for the interpolation.  If smaller local neighborhoods are desired, they would be involved in one (very fast) precomputation step, where the weights `xy` are computed, but otherwise nothing else would change.

[image: Plot]

*The windspeeds during the first hour are plotted as circles whose areas are proportional to the average speed during the year; the averages range from 1 to 5.9 m/sec.*

**There is a price to pay:** this method precomputes some values and stores them in RAM.  This quarter-size calculation required 6.75 GB RAM.  A full-size calculation would therefore request 27 GB RAM.  If you don't have that much, though, it is a simple matter to carve up the grid into smaller rectangles, do the calculation for each rectangle separately, and mosaic the pieces afterwards.  The total calculation time would not appreciably increase.

Complete code follows.

```r
set.seed(23)
n.points <- 60
n.hours <- 24 * 365
n.x <- 620/2          # Number of columns in grid
n.y <- 250/2          # Number of rows in grid
threshold <- 5        # Wind speed threshold
#
# The data: point locations.
#
points <- matrix(rnorm(n.points*2, 10^5, 10^4), ncol=2)
points <- points[order(points[,1]), ] # Sort by x-coordinate for testing
#
# Expand the extent of the points by about 10% to define the extent of the grid.
#
ranges <- apply(points, 2, range)
d.r <- diff(ranges)
x <- seq(ranges[1,1] - .05*d.r[1], ranges[2,1] + 0.05*d.r[1], length.out=n.x)
y <- seq(ranges[1,2] - .05*d.r[2], ranges[2,2] + 0.05*d.r[2], length.out=n.y)
#
# Obtain the inverse squared distances to the points.
#
distance.to <- function(u, x, y, eps=10^(-8)) {
  e <- eps * (max(x) - min(x) + max(y) - min(y))^2
  return(1 / (e + (x-u[1])^2 + (y-u[2])^2))
}
system.time(
  xy <- apply(points, 1, 
            function(u) outer(x, y, function(x0, y0) distance.to(u, x0, y0)))
  )
#
# The data: an array of values, one per column.
#
p.x <- points[,1]
z.scale <- rgamma(n.points, 5, scale=((p.x - min(x))/10^4 + 2)/50)
z <- matrix(rgamma(n.points * n.hours, 10, scale=z.scale), nrow=n.points)
z[z > 10] <- NA  # Introduce some missing values
#
# Perform the interpolation, thresholding, and averaging.
#
system.time({
  one <- !is.na(z)                  # Indicates the valid values
  z[is.na(z)] <- 0                  # Replace missing with 0
  thresh <- threshold * xy %*% one  # Compute the denominators
  a <- matrix(rowMeans(xy %*% z >= thresh), n.x, n.y)
  })
#
# Plot the results.
#
z.sum <- rowSums(z)
z.max <- max(z.sum)
z.root <- sqrt(z.sum / z.max) * 3
filled.contour(x=x, y=y, a, color.palette=terrain.colors, 
               plot.axes={axis(1); axis(2); 
                          points(points, col="Black", cex=z.root)},
               main="Proportion of Year at or above 5 m/sec",
               xlab="Easting")
```

Comment: I like your answer better.

Comment: Thank you very much, whuber, for taking the time to give this very detailed response.  This is very helpful and something I can try and experiment with. Let me give a little more background into what I'm trying to do:  I'm trying to create a methodology of displaying the frequency of favorable wind conditions at different locations if I were to have archived gridded wind model data for a year.  Right now, the wind data at the resolution I need is not archived so it is not available.  So, I'm trying to come up with a plan of attack assuming this data was available.  ..cont'd..

Comment: ..In order to best simulate this data, I wanted to create the rasters of wind model data for 2012 by using observed wind data and putting it in a table, then using some form of interpolation (wanted Kriging, but have had issues normalizing the data) and then reclassify them, sum them, and display the final results as percentage of favorable wind conditions at each location (total favorably modeled wind conditions in 2012 divided by total modeled wind conditions in 2012)

Comment: But it might be that this method is not the best and I need to rethink it.  If the process of creating the 8,760 rasters takes several hours (at best) to complete I would be okay with it (whether by model or Python).  It might be troublesome if the process were going to take more than a day or two though.  In retrospect I should have been more clear about what I'm trying to do in my original question, so I apologize.

Comment: It's clear what you're trying to do, Daniel: this is precisely the kind of information needed for designing wind farms (because turbines need minimum windspeeds in order to operate). Windspeeds tend to have skewed distributions (which is why I simulated them from Gamma distributions), but that can be handled in kriging via a non-linear rexpression, such as the square root, or with a GLM. Of more import is the likelihood that winds are controlled by local topography, perhaps changing abruptly in speed and direction at ridge lines. Kriging can include this kind of information; IDW can't.

Comment: The argument for speed is this: since the results for a full year will differ from those obtained for a shorter period, you want to do a full year. After seeing it, you will develop ideas to improve it. This feedback between what you are trying to do and what emerges is crucial; you don't want to have to wait hours or days for it. Moreover (this is based on experience) it is likely something will go wrong while computing 8760 grids, causing you to lose all the results and have to restart. Initially, use a coarse resolution and subsample the times to get the calculation down to a few seconds.

Comment: Yes after thinking on this some more, I think you're absolutely right on this method.  I'll read up on R this afternoon and see if I can figure out how to read my data into R, look into substituting sqaure root or GLM in for IDW and exporting to ESRI.  Thank you again for the help.  I'll update this soon with any results and/or questions I think of.

Comment: Lets say I already have 8,760 raster data sets for 2012 and I'd like to reclassify them as above (cell value of "1" for wind speed >=5m/s and "0" for all others), add them all up and divide each cell by the total number of rasters (8,760) to get a result of percentage of suitable obs.  Would this be something the above R code would be able to do with some tweaking?

Comment: Yes--you have to read the rasters in one at a time; once in RAM, the reclassification and averaging are almost instantaneous.  This process will be I/O bound, limited by the amount of time needed to read those rasters.  It will help if they are in binary format datasets; you can use `gdal` to read them.

Comment: Thanks, whuber.  I've been going over your code and looking at R tutorials and other code examples.  If I have a directory of many rasters in, lets say GeoTIFF format, would I then be able to read those all into R with something like this: `library(rgdal)`, `my_tiff_files = dir("C:/dir/subdir", pattern="*.tif")` and `data <- readGDAL(my_tiff_files)`? And once they are all read in can I just define variables from within the rasters and then run the calculations as you posted in your code above?  Or would I need to incorporate some for loops or something to process the multiple rasters?

Comment: I would recommend reading the grids in one at a time so you don't run out of RAM. That would be done within a loop, of course--although in `R` it would likely be coded with a version of `apply` rather than explicitly. `R` prefers to operate on entire rasters at once: with a single command you will compare all values to the threshold of 5 m/sec and with another you will add that result to a cumulative raster. That's about all there is to it.

Comment: Okay, sorry to keep peppering you with questions. Been trying my best over the last few days in free time to read up on R, the `apply` functions, etc.  So, would the reading in and processing need to all be included in the loop? Or would the loop only be necessary to read in the grids one at a time?  Also, does this beginning of a loop look like it would work to read in grids one at a time?  `model_data <- list.files(path=getwd())` `for (i in model_data){ my_data <- readGDAL(model_data[i])`. And then maybe embed sapply in the loop or would I need to stack the rasters? Thanks again for the help

Comment: Also, my apologies...I feel like you have probably given me ample hints to be able to figure this out by now, but it's not quite all clicking yet for me.  Your patience and help is greatly appreciated.  I think I'm more of a visual learner with this...I've gotten the most out of going over your above code and reading the code of others so far.